# How can I speed up slow-loading, template-generated MXDs?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, mxd

I have an ArcMap template (.mxt) file which causes .mxd documents created with it to take 5-10 minutes to load (if it ever loads).  Even after stripping out all the data sources and tables, the issue still persists.

Once it loads, it handles fine.  Any general speculation of what could be causing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try using MXDdoctor and ArcGIS Document Defragmenter.

Comment: A file run through MXDDoctor was clipped to 70% of the file size and it seems to perform better, though is still slow.  DocDefragmenter took half the size out, but didn't seem to solve the issue.

Comment: Have recently found a new tool, available even since 9.3.1 up to 10.2 versions. http://blogs.esri.com/esri/supportcenter/2012/04/03/new-arcgis-performance-calibration-tool/ PerfQAnalyzer for ArcGIS

Answer (score 6):

Did you perhaps have a Bing layer in it? Or maybe even an ArcGIS Online layer? I think I have some documents like that. ArcMap 10 seems to be a bit slower on most file loads anyway. I just installed the patch for the file dialog performance ESRI website.

Comment: It did actually have a public arcgis service, I'll give that patch a shot thanks

Comment: What is the "file dialog performance ESRI website" you mentioned?

Answer (score 4):

To address this issue, I have cleared the contents of the Results tab in ArcToolbox and made sure only needed extensions were enabled.  Also, I have renamed the normal template because it was suggested that this template was corrupted.  I found this link helpful http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=982&t=274915.